# Discord.NET | ConnectAsync method timing out

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm just trying to make my discord bot join the channel I'm in. When I call ConnectAsync, it works properly and my bot does join the channel, but the method keeps hanging and times out in about 15 seconds, also disconnecting the bot from the channel.
I have done some research but all I could find was people saying to make sure the HandleMessage method is asynchronous, which it is. Besides, the other 'await' methods inside it work properly, such as 'SendMessageAsync'. What can I do to fix it?
OBS: Using ASP.NET Core 6.

Here's my code:

```
private async Task HandleMessageReceived(SocketMessage message)
{
     if (message.Author.Id == _client.CurrentUser.Id)
     {
          return;
     }

     else if (message.Content == "!ping")
     {
          await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Pong!");
     }

     else if (message.Content == "!join" && message.Author is IGuildUser guildUser)
     {
          // Get the user's voice channel
          _voiceChannel = guildUser.VoiceChannel;

          // Connect to the voice channel
          if (_voiceChannel != null)
          {
          await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("I joined the channel.");
          var audioClient = await guildUser.VoiceChannel.ConnectAsync();
          }
          else
          {
          await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("You need to be in a voice channel to use this command.");
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The command's Run Mode must be set to `RunMode.Async`, otherwise, being connected to a voice channel will block the gateway thread:

```
[Command("name", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
```

You can refer to the sample code in [this document](https://discordnet.dev/guides/voice/sending-voice.html#joining-a-channel).

If you've tried this and the problem persists, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use the [TextCommand Framework](https://discordnet.dev/guides/text_commands/intro.html) as Chen suggested. You can also achieve the async runmode in wrapping your code in a `Task.Run`:

```cs
// Connect to the voice channel
if (_voiceChannel != null)
{
     _ = Task.Run(async () =>
     {
          await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("I joined the channel.");
          var audioClient = await guildUser.VoiceChannel.ConnectAsync();
     });
}
```

But note that Text Commands are deprecated by discord (as verified bots need the message content intent for text based commands to work) and you should migrate to [Slash Commands](https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_framework/intro.html#slash-commands) soon.